# TFT Connection through API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to submit issues to the Team Foundation Server through it's API. we have an "OnDemand" version of the TFT, not the "Onpremises" version.

I'm being unable to find any applicable examples with "OnDemad" API connection using a C#.NET application.

For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14108/Web-Forms-for-Submitting-Issues-to-Team-Foundation

are there any examples for OnDemand version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code used to excersise the TFS API is identical regardless of whether you are using TF Server or TF Service.

The only real difference is authentication. You can either implement Microsoft ID (was Live ID) authentication, which is hard. Or you can use the service credentials. This is how the local build servers are configured to work against the service.

You can use the TFS Credential Manager to retrieve the correct username and password from the online service.

http://nakedalm.com/tfs-service-credential-viewer/